# How to schedule a Kubernetes object creation at a later time?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I have two Custom Resource Definitions (CRDs), backup and scheduled backup.
And I would like to run a backup operation at a specific time, following is the architecture that I came up with which gives me a guarantee that the backup operation will be triggered using the CronJob.

I see there is a `creationTimestamp` in the kubernetes object, I was wondering if I can specify a future `creationTimestamp` will that create the CRD object at the later stage which will remove the need for having the CronJob and having a custom image for CronJob with k8s resources and logic of creating the CRD object?

[image]

Comment: Does the scheduled backup CRD not handle the scheduled creation of backup jobs? Are you using an existing product like valero or are you writing an operator?

Comment: I am not using Velero. In order to create the backup job at a scheduled time, I will have to create a CronJob (and create a docker image with the required resources to interact with k8s cluster) which will create the backup CRD.

Comment: The `creationTimestamp` fiels is auto-generated by a server. You can't use it to postpone creation of resources. You could try [KEDA](https://keda.sh/) or [kube-schedule-scaler](https://hub.docker.com/r/citizensadvice/kube-schedule-scaler), but I'm not 100% sure those will fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, @p10l for sharing the link, the requirement is about scheduling an object to a future timestamp, not an event-driven scaling.